# typescript overload mui interface, type is not assignable

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, material-ui, datagrid

i cant find any solutions for my problem,

```
    export const columns: GridColDef[] = [
      {
        field: 'testdate',
        headerName: 'testdate',
        type: 'date',
        valueFormatter: (param: GridValueFormatterParams) => {
          return new Date(param.value).toLocaleDateString('de-DE', {
            year: '2-digit',
            month: '2-digit',
            day: '2-digit',
          });
        },
      },
    ]
```

I get this error:

> No overload matches this call.   Overload 1 of 4, '(value: string |
> number | Date): Date', gave the following error.
> Argument of type 'GridCellValue' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | number | Date'.
> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | number | Date'.   Overload 2 of 4, '(value: string | number): Date', gave the
> following error.
> Argument of type 'GridCellValue' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | number'.
> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | number'.

I know this error come, because the param.value is a GridCellValue which can be a:
string | number | boolean | Date ...
And the new Date expect a string | number or Date. So how can i fix this error?
many thanks!

Comment: So in your case, what you want the behevior when the GridCellValue is boolean and passed to Date ?

Comment: as a default behavior , get a date from boolean return 1970-01-01T00:00:00.001Z.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code example , the problem come from that the value could be undefined while Date arg should be date, number or string.

Here is an example illustrating the same issue so you can understand how to resolve it.

```
type DateType = string | number | Date;

type CellType = DateType | undefined ;


const formatDate = (value: Required<DateType>) =>  new Date(value);



const validValue: DateType = "18/07/1994";

const invalidValue : CellType = Math.floor(Math.random()*4)>1 ? "18/07/1999" : undefined ;

const valid = formatDate(validValue);
const invalid = formatDate(invalidValue as DateType );

console.log("valid",valid);
console.log("invalid", invalid);
```

The hack is to force casting to Date type

```
invalidValue as DateType
```

Comment: Now it is working! :) Thank you a lot!